# List files in a package from Android App returns null

Tags: java, android, file, package, apk

I develop an Android App, in the main activity i want to list all files in a specific package using the following line of code:

```
String[] files = new File("src/com/android/app/").list();
```

It returns null !? Is there something wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Kon: I use the same syntax in Java SE application and it works, I think something relative to the structure of the App when installed (APK) in the Android device

Comment: `src/com/android/app/` suggests files in an Android app project, specifically a directory of Java source code. That will not exist at runtime as files on the filesystem in any directory, let alone in the broken directory that you are trying to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, I'm wondering how the project structure is represented in the APK file !

Comment: The project structure generally isn't represented in the APK file. This isn't Web development, where everything is in plain text files. Your Java code gets compiled into Dalvik bytecode, your resources and manifest are converted into binary files, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem, while all classes compiled by the Dalvik Virtual Machine, we must use DexFile class [Dex File documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html).

```
public List<String> getClasses(Context context, String package) {
    List<String> classes = new LinkedList<String>();
    try {
        DexFile dexFile = new DexFile(context.getPackageCodePath());
            for (Enumeration<String> iter = dexFile.entries(); iter.hasMoreElements();) {
                String currentClass = iter.nextElement();
                    if (currentClass.contains(package)) {
                            classes.add(currentClass);
                    }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) for the `File` class:

> User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent pathname
>   strings to name files and directories. This class presents an
>   abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical pathnames. An
>   abstract pathname has two components:
>
> ```
> An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX root directory, or "\\\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and
> A sequence of zero or more string names.
> ```

So you are missing the prefix String, it seems. In other words, the pathname is not relative, it is absolute.

Comment: I used `System.getProperty("file.separator")` but in vain, I got the same error, I think the project structure change when packaging as APK file. I'v tried also `String[] files = new File("src/com/android/app/").list();` I got this in files array: config, cache, acct, vendor, d, ..., data, root, dev. Now I'm trying to know the structure of APK file to retrieve the path to compiled classes

Comment: The statement you cite says that the prefix is optional, so it can't be 'missing', and you've missed the real problem entirely.